Express.js API Integration with SkyScanner API Fails to retrieve flights data
I'm working on integrating the Skyscanner Flights Scraper API using Express.js and Axios. The goal is to fetch flight data using the /flights/search-everywhere endpoint. Here's what I've done so far:

Successfully obtained the fromEntityId from the /flights/auto-complete endpoint.

Attempted to use this fromEntityId to search flights via /flights/search-everywhere.
When I test this in the RapidAPI Playground, it works perfectly and returns valid flight data. However, when I run the same query through my local server and Postman, it always returns:
{
  "message": "No flights found"
}



Observations:

In RapidAPI: The request returns valid flight data.
In Postman: The request always responds with "message": "No flights found".

I suspect there's an issue with how I'm passing the fromEntityId or how Axios handles the request, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Things I've tried:

Verified that the API key and host are correct.
Double-checked the request headers and parameters against the RapidAPI playground.
Logged the fromEntityId to ensure it's being received correctly in the server.

/* server.js */

app.post('/flights', async (req, res) => {
    const { fromEntityId } = req.body;

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://${API_HOST}/flights/search-everywhere`, {
            headers: {
                'X-RapidAPI-Host': API_HOST,
                'X-RapidAPI-Key': API_KEY,
            },
            params: {
                query: fromEntityId,
            },
        });

        const flights = response.data?.data?.results || null;

        if (!flights) {
            return res.json({ message: 'No flights found' });
        }

        res.json(flights);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching flights:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error fetching flights. Please try again.' });
    }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});



PostMan doesn't work

API website works


Your post contains several indicators that ChatGPT or another LLM was used to generate it. For a variety of reasons, the use of such generative AI tools is strictly disallowed on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove and replace content that was generated using these tools.

Have you tried attaching a debugger at your backend and check the response? For instance if the statuscode shows success (ie 2xx)? Did you inspect if the response contains any data at all? If yes, what does it contain? Did you check, if the fromEntityParameter is correctly set?  Please add all those information to the question
